# How do you fix the grating after you break the time-shifting clock?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

I discovered that, after breaking the clock, you can attempt to fix it with a Lore:Mystical + Intelligence check!

This is the clue I got afterwards:

> A glowing, viscous fluid flows up from the ground to the top of a
>   chamber inside the device. Sifting through the synth shards, you find
>   pieces ofa  filigreed grating - diamonds within diamonds. It has been
>   shattered into several pieces by your blow, making the remnants hard
>   to find. Fixtures around the sides of the chamber suggest that the
>   grating was attached in the midst of the fluid, perhaps as some sort
>   of sieve.
>
> The grating is too shattered to fix, but perhaps you could find a
>   replacement.

and

> A circinate symbol is etched inside of the chamber like a maker's
>   mark. You commit it to memory.

This could open up a whole lot of great options! We would
 be able to turn the day to night, free the Nychthemeron, and then fix
 the clock, which would still allow us to convince the Cultists that
 we're the Changing God without using Tidal Surge!

How do we replace the grating? I spoke to the Master Foreman, Prata, Aligern, Callistege and the scientists in the Order of Truth. It wasn't a dialogue option. I don't remember finding any gratings on my travels.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. I inspected the machine in the North West, next to the Genocide. It gave me a Fractal Lattice. I replaced the grating with it.

After entering the clock and leaving, I got the option to interact with it. I then was able to use a Tidal Surge to move it back into daytime.